# Button background only Updating on One Button

Tags: java, android

I am making a board game where I use buttons to create the actual board itself. All empty board locations have a button background color of white, and all occupied board locations are colored in the players colors. Now the code that controls the users moves works with no problems and so does the class AI. The method aiTurn() returns an object which contains a char to let the class know what type of move is being made, and the index's from where the character is moving from and to.

The code and produceure of the method works, but ever since adding the for loop (to make sure the AI completely finished its turn) only the last iteration of the for loop seems to update the background color of the buttons and all previous iterations are ignored. For example if the ai rolls a 6 and moves a piece from the home location to the main board and as results gets to roll again and rolls a 2, the result should be the home location where it was taken from should be set to white and the button on the main board 2 away should be set to the players color. However, only the main board button color is set becasue thats done in the 2nd iteration after the 2nd roll and the inital color change of the home button to white in the first iteration was not completed. The code to the method is below:

```
public void onClickNextTurn(View view){
        playerTurn=2;
        boolean turnFinished=false;

        for (int x=0; x<2 && !turnFinished; x++) {
            diceRoll();
            MoveTriplet result = ai[0].aiTurn(this.boardPieceLocations, this.homeLocations, this.finishLocations, this.roll, 2);

            if (result.getMoveType() == 'a') { //The Artificial Opponent is moving from one board location to another AND gets to roll again
                this.boardPieceLocations[result.getPreviousIndex()] = 0;
                this.boardPieceLocations[result.getNextIndex()] = playerTurn;
                this.buttons[result.getPreviousIndex()].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorHoles));
                this.buttons[result.getNextIndex()].setBackgroundColor(colors[playerTurn - 1]);
            } else if (result.getMoveType() == 'b') { //The Artificial Opponent is moving from one home location to the board AND gets to roll again
                System.out.println("Player turn= " + playerTurn);
                System.out.println("Next Location= " + result.getNextIndex());
                this.homeLocations[playerTurn - 1][result.getPreviousIndex()] = 0;
                this.boardPieceLocations[result.getNextIndex()] = playerTurn;
                this.homeButtons[playerTurn - 1][result.getPreviousIndex()].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorHoles));
                this.buttons[result.getNextIndex()].setBackgroundColor(colors[playerTurn - 1]);
            } else if (result.getMoveType() == 'c') { //The Artificial Opponent is moving from one board location to finish location AND gets to roll again
                this.boardPieceLocations[result.getPreviousIndex()] = 0;
                this.finishLocations[playerTurn - 1][result.getNextIndex()] = playerTurn;
                this.buttons[result.getPreviousIndex()].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorHoles));
                this.finishButtons[playerTurn - 1][result.getNextIndex()].setBackgroundColor(colors[playerTurn - 1]);
            } else if (result.getMoveType() == 'd') { //The Artificial Opponent is moving from one finish location to another AND gets to roll again
                this.finishLocations[playerTurn - 1][result.getPreviousIndex()] = 0;
                this.finishLocations[playerTurn - 1][result.getNextIndex()] = playerTurn;
                this.finishButtons[playerTurn - 1][result.getPreviousIndex()].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorHoles));
                this.finishButtons[playerTurn - 1][result.getNextIndex()].setBackgroundColor(colors[playerTurn - 1]);
            } else if (result.getMoveType() == 'e') { //The Artificial Opponent is moving from one board location to finish location
                this.finishLocations[playerTurn - 1][result.getPreviousIndex()] = 0;
                this.finishLocations[playerTurn - 1][result.getNextIndex()] = playerTurn;
                this.finishButtons[playerTurn - 1][result.getPreviousIndex()].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorHoles));
                this.finishButtons[playerTurn - 1][result.getNextIndex()].setBackgroundColor(colors[playerTurn - 1]);
                turnFinished=true;
            } else if (result.getMoveType() == 'f') { //The Artificial Opponent is moving from one finish location to another
                this.finishLocations[playerTurn - 1][result.getPreviousIndex()] = 0;
                this.finishLocations[playerTurn - 1][result.getNextIndex()] = playerTurn;
                this.finishButtons[playerTurn - 1][result.getPreviousIndex()].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorHoles));
                this.finishButtons[playerTurn - 1][result.getNextIndex()].setBackgroundColor(colors[playerTurn - 1]);
                turnFinished=true;
            } else if (result.getMoveType() == 'h') { //The Artificial Opponent is moving from one home location to the board
                this.homeLocations[playerTurn - 1][result.getPreviousIndex()] = 0;
                this.boardPieceLocations[result.getNextIndex()] = 2;
                this.homeButtons[playerTurn - 1][result.getPreviousIndex()].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorHoles));
                this.buttons[result.getNextIndex()].setBackgroundColor(colors[playerTurn - 1]);
                turnFinished=true;
            } else if (result.getMoveType() == 'r') { //The Artificial Opponent is moving from one board location to another
                this.boardPieceLocations[result.getPreviousIndex()] = 0;
                this.boardPieceLocations[result.getNextIndex()] = 2;
                this.buttons[result.getPreviousIndex()].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorHoles));
                this.buttons[result.getNextIndex()].setBackgroundColor(colors[playerTurn - 1]);
                turnFinished=true;
            }
            //Else to just roll again with no movement
        }
```

My quesition is what is causing the prorgam to only update the color of the button in the last iteration of the for loop and how can I fix it? Thank you in advance

Comment: I think the problem is here ai[0] try to put x here like ai[x]

Comment: ai[0] should be correct because I am just calling the first artificial opponent to take its turn. All the for loop is doing is making sure if the ai rolls a 6 or the board is empty that it gets to take another turn, nothing to do with picking which opponent is supposed to be taking the turn